# Setting ActiveX property with optional inputs

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, com, activex

I am trying to set an activeX property through javascript. I am using the OLE/COM object viewer and the setting looks like this:

```
[id(0x0000001e), propput, helpstring("property Param")]
void Param(
                [in] ParamCodes Params, 
                [in, optional, defaultvalue(1)] long lRec, 
                [in, optional, defaultvalue(1)] long lEntry, 
                [in] VARIANT rhs);
```

I can access the parameter by `var channel = mvc.Param(0x2004001a)`. However if I try to set the property using `mvc.Param(0x2004001a) = 100` the javascript stops running. I also cannot access or set any of the other records using the optional parameters using `mvc.Param(0x2004001a,4,5)`. Am I using the incorrect syntax for this or will I have to go down calling the `mvc.Invoke()` road?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method uses optional/defaultvalue attributes incorrectly and I don't think this is going or expected to work. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366793%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The MIDL compiler accepts the following parameter ordering (from left-to-right):
>
> - Required parameters (parameters that do not have the [defaultvalue] or [optional] attributes),
> - optional parameters with or without the [defaultvalue] attribute,
> - parameters with the [optional] attribute and without the [defaultvalue] attribute,
> - [lcid] parameter, if any,
> - [retval] parameter

You are making an assumption that last `[in]` argument will be property assignment value and can be excluded from the list above enabling you to use optional accessor parameters, however it is not a documented behavior, and then - perhaps even more important - this is hardly supported by JS engine, which has its own constraints on automation properties.

Taking optional parameters out, it is unclear what `ParamCodes` is and interface attributes/definition, which might have issues on its own preventing you from using the property in JS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have solved the problem. It had to do with how the COM object was opening a file (read only). I set the correct property and was able to access the `ParamCode` I needed by `mvc.Param(0x2004001a,1,1) = 100`..

Comment: Makes sense now, as you provided all arguments explicitly - your optionality attributes are likely to be ignored due to reasons mentioned above.